# Wordpress User Portal

Tags: plugins, users

So I work for a small developer who does some of their lightweight web projects on wordpress. We're searching for a plugin that would allow non tech-savvy people to easily make new posts and pages using the theme and development.

Basically, if we built a site for say, a chamber of commerce, is it possible to build in an easy way for county workers to upload new content without going through the wordpress dashboard?

We do use Elementor but even that might be on the complex side. A plugin for Elementor that allows simple dragging and dropping of content would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, turns out the Elementor Role Manager does pretty much this exactly by limiting out the more confusing or dangerous elements from being edited.